# Прошу помощи с кодом JS

Tags: javascript, html

Есть кусок кода

```html
<div class="col-1">

    <div class="bts">

    </div>

</div>

<div class="col-2">

    <div class="fan" data-id="yes">

    </div>

</div>
```

У класса "fan" изменяется `data-id` (YES и NO)

Как мне сделать так, чтобы при `data-id="yes"` удалялся `<div class="col-1">`, а при `data-id="no"` удалялся `<div class="col-2">`?

Comment: Каким образом меняете `data-id`, есть какая-то функция это делающая?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так..

```js
if (document.querySelector('[data-id=yes]')) {
  document.querySelector('.col-1').remove()
} else if (document.querySelector('[data-id=no]')) {
  document.querySelector('.col-2').remove()
}
```

```css
.col-2 {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.col-1 {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-1">

  <div class="bts">

  </div>

</div>

<div class="col-2">

  <div class="fan" data-id="yes">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю!! Вы очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

1. Следить любым из известных способов за изменением `element.dataset.id` (где `element` - это `document.querySelector(".fan")`). Самый логичный способ - выполнять действия, перечисленные ниже в том месте, где изменяете значение `data-id`;
2. При изменении проверять, равно ли `element.dataset.id` `"yes"`;
3. Если равно, удалять `divCol1` методом `.remove()`: `divCol1.remove()` (где `divCol1` - это `document.querySelector(".col-1")`);
4. В противном случае удалять `divCol2`: `divCol2.remove()` (где `divCol2` - это `document.querySelector(".col-2")`).

Comment: А можно в виде кода, как мне проверять равно или нет? Please

Comment: @Психолог а тройным `=` и проверяйте: что-то типа `if (element.dataset.id === "yes") {...}`